# Remove HTML tags with specific content using Regex

Tags: regex

I want to remove an HTML tag but only with specific content is appear, like this:

```
<strong>\u00a0</strong>
```

I want to remove the tag only if \u00a0 is appearing inside the tag. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is to match the exact string `\u00a0`, then the regex is just about escaping a couple of slashes:

```
s/<strong>\\u00a0<\/strong>//g
```

Or, more readable:

```
s|<strong>\\u00a0</strong>||g
```

If you mean to match the actual unicode character `U+00A0`, then the regex is:

- Non-PCRE syntax:

```
s/<strong>\u00a0<\/strong>//g
```

- PCRE syntax:

```
s/<strong>\x{00a0}<\/strong>//g
```